# How to convert Json to string and then show in list

Tags: c#

How to convert json to string and show in list this is my code.....

```
 private void btnKeywords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string document = string.Empty;
                if (chkDocument.Checked == true)
                {
                    document = txtDocument1.Text.Trim() + " " + txtDocument2.Text.Trim();
                } else
                {
                    document = txtDocument1.Text.Trim();
                }                
                string result = clas.keywords(document);             
                dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                List<keywords> Keyboardist =response.keywords.ToObject<List<keywords>>();              
                txtResult.Text`enter code here` = result;
                txtResult.Text = result;
            }
```

Comment: JSON is a string. Can you be a little more specific, please?

Comment: what is `keywords` here? is it custom class?

Comment: It is a public Class name

Comment: Please elaborate your code. what is `clas.keywords(document)`? why `dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                List<keywords> Keyboardist =response.keywords.ToObject<List<keywords>>();              
                txtResult.Text`enter code here = result;
`

Comment: Keywords is a public class name

Answer (score 0):

> You can convert string directly to list like this :

`List<string> Keyboardlist = document.Split(' ').ToList();`

> Otherwise your string needs to be in proper JSON format and what you
>   can do is something like shown below :

`List<object> Keyboardlist= new List<object>();`  
`Keyboardlist= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(json);`